# Pigeonhole Principle for pairs of even integers sharing the same remainder

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I have the following problem:

"Let P(n) denote “If any n even integers are selected, then there must be a pair who share the same remainder under integer division by 12.”
Let n* denote the smallest value of n for which P(n) is true.  What is n*?  For your stated value of  n*, prove that P(n*) is true and that P(n*−1) is false.[Note:This proves that your stated value of n* is the smallest value of n for which P(n) is true.]"

I am not sure how to apply the pigeonhole principle in this problem so as to prove it. Can someone help me or guide me in the right direction? We did very brief examples in class and nothing similar to this.

I noticed the possible remainders will be 12  from 0-11 , so i guess these are the pigeonholes but it is unclear how i can proceed.

Comment: Hint: you only pick even numbers so the possible numbers $\mod 12$ are $0,2,..,10$ what happens when you pick an extra number? What if you pick all of them different?

Comment: Oh yes the remainder should be 0,2,4,6,8,10 then i need at least seven even numbers so that there is a pair that shares the same remainder since the possible remainders are 6?is that logic correct?

Comment: Yes exactly and if you have 6 or less all of them could be different